# SQL get entire row dependant on first column

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm making a VB6 program and I would like to get information from a DB.

But I only need the information of one row in a table

Currently I have this as my query

```
SELECT CertNo FROM STICKER
```

this populates the listbox with all the items in CertNo,
is there a way to get information dependent on a variable, something like

```
SELECT CertNo FROM STICKER WHERE CertNo = 10000
```

it would get all the columns from the row where the CertNo = 10000

Code to grab data:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long

Datalist.Clear

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                              "Data Source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\dbAdd.mdb;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT CertNo FROM STICKER WHERE CertNo = '10303';", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

rs.MoveFirst

While Not rs.EOF
    Datalist.AddItem rs.Fields(0)
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Missing operator I don't think `SELECT CertNo FROM STICKER WHERE CertNo = 10000` is correct

Comment: try `SELECT CertNo FROM STICKER WHERE CertNo = '10000'` if CertNo field is store as string

Comment: That works but I think it will only get the CertNo column, how could i have '10000' as a variable such as Data1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to get results for field like `Data1`

```
rs.Open "SELECT CertNo FROM STICKER WHERE CertNo = '"& Data1 &"';", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

if you want multiple columns return from sql, do as below

```
rs.Open "SELECT CertNo, IssueDate FROM STICKER WHERE CertNo = '"& Data1 &"';", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

and in the loop

```
While Not rs.EOF
    Datalist.AddItem rs.Fields(0) & rs.Fields(1)
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, would this only pull results from CertNo? I would ideally be able to get results from different columns within that row, for example I have another columns called IssueDate, would that also be able to be included?

Comment: @user2341069 yes, select columns which you want. check my updated answer